# $injector:modulerr loading heroku app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, heroku, meanjs

i'm trying to deploy my mean.js https://github.com/bogoquiz/trendtwitter.git app to heroku shielded-journey-5640.herokuapp.com/. somehow the app on heroku is loading the error.

Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.28/$injector/modulerr?p0=trend-twitter2&p1=%5B%24injector%3Amodulerr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.2.28%2F%24injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3DngTable%26p1%3D%255B%2524injector%253Anomod%255D%2520http%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.2.28%252F%2524injector%252Fnomod%253Fp0%253DngTable%250Az%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Ftrendmedia.herokuapp.com%252Flib%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A6%253A450%250AYc%252Fb.module%253C%252F%253C%252Fb%255Be%255D%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Ftrendmedia.herokuapp.com%252Flib%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A20%253A1%250AYc%252Fb.module%253C%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Ftrendmedia.herokuapp.com%252Flib%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A20%253A1%250Ae%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Ftrendmedia.herokuapp.com%252Flib%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A33%253A267%250Ar%2540http%253A%252F%252Ftrendmedia.herokuapp.com%252Flib%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A288%250Ae%2540http%253A%252F%252Ftrendmedia.herokuapp.com%252Flib%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A33%253A207%250Ae%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Ftrendmedia.herokuapp.com%252Flib%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A33%253A284%250Ar%2540http%253A%252F%252Ftrendmedia.herokuapp.com%252Flib%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A288%250Ae%2540http%253A%252F%252Ftrendmedia.herokuapp.com%252Flib%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A33%253A207%250Aec%2540http%253A%252F%252Ftrendmedia.herokuapp.com%252Flib%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A36%253A309%250Adc%252Fc%2540http%253A%252F%252Ftrendmedia.herokuapp.com%252Flib%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A18%253A170%250Adc%2540http%253A%252F%252Ftrendmedia.herokuapp.com%252Flib%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A18%253A387%250A%2540http%253A%252F%252Ftrendmedia.herokuapp.com%252Fdist%252Fapplication.min.js%253A1%253A959%250Aa%2540http%253A%252F%252Ftrendmedia.herokuapp.com%252Flib%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A146%253A93%250Ane%252Fc%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Ftrendmedia.herokuapp.com%252Flib%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A31%253A223%250Ar%2540http%253A%252F%252Ftrendmedia.herokuapp.com%252Flib%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A288%250Ane%252Fc%2540http%253A%252F%252Ftrendmedia.herokuapp.com%252Flib%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A31%253A207%250A%0Az%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Ftrendmedia.herokuapp.com%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A6%3A450%0Ae%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Ftrendmedia.herokuapp.com%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A34%3A97%0Ar%40http%3A%2F%2Ftrendmedia.herokuapp.com%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A7%3A288%0Ae%40http%3A%2F%2Ftrendmedia.herokuapp.com%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A33%3A207%0Ae%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Ftrendmedia.herokuapp.com%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A33%3A284%0Ar%40http%3A%2F%2Ftrendmedia.herokuapp.com%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A7%3A288%0Ae%40http%3A%2F%2Ftrendmedia.herokuapp.com%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A33%3A207%0Aec%40http%3A%2F%2Ftrendmedia.herokuapp.com%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A36%3A309%0Adc%2Fc%40http%3A%2F%2Ftrendmedia.herokuapp.com%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A18%3A170%0Adc%40http%3A%2F%2Ftrendmedia.herokuapp.com%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A18%3A387%0A%40http%3A%2F%2Ftrendmedia.herokuapp.com%2Fdist%2Fapplication.min.js%3A1%3A959%0Aa%40http%3A%2F%2Ftrendmedia.herokuapp.com%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A146%3A93%0Ane%2Fc%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Ftrendmedia.herokuapp.com%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A31%3A223%0Ar%40http%3A%2F%2Ftrendmedia.herokuapp.com%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A7%3A288%0Ane%2Fc%40http%3A%2F%2Ftrendmedia.herokuapp.com%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A31%3A207%0A

Comment: you angular module has not initialized, you may missed your app file reference..

Comment: how initialize the angular module in heroku, in local no have this problem  and I am newbie

Comment: are you using js minification?

Comment: yes, as used in stack MEAN.JS

Comment: then you must follow the ng-annotation https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate dependancy injection

Comment: when i use build task grunt make the minification with ng-annotate and error continue

Comment: I found that the problem is in ng-table in the / public / config file. remove the dependency and loads the page but now the problem is that I need ng-table for other functionality of the application

Comment: can you upload you some code? how you are loading dependency in app.

Comment: 'use strict';

// Init the application configuration module for AngularJS application
var ApplicationConfiguration = (function() {
 // Init module configuration options
 var applicationModuleName = 'trend-twitter2';
 var applicationModuleVendorDependencies = ['ngResource', 'ngCookies',  'ngAnimate',  'ngTouch',  'ngSanitize',  'ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.utils', 'btford.socket-io', 'ngTable'];

Comment: all the proyect have in https://github.com/bogoquiz/trendtwitter

Comment: the depency intection ngtable that no work is   /public/config  and where use ngtable is  \public\modules\customers\controllers/customers.client.controller.js

Comment: try `angular.module('customers', ['ngTable']).` did you added all relatives files which are required like ngTable.js, angular-router.js, etc.